# Build apk with dynamic feature modules from command line without bundletool

Tags: android, adb

We have several dynamic feature modules. We want to easily build a debug version of our app with ADB and sideload. When we use `./gradlew app:assembleDebug` our dynamic modules are not included in the apk. I know there is a way to do this through Android Studio:

[image]

But is there a way to use ADB to do this? Basically just say "include all the dynamic feature modules as if they were part of the base module".

I also know that each developer can assemble/build an apk for their test device with `bundletool`. But this multi step process slows down those of us who prefer CL gradle.

Answer (score 0):

Either I must have been using an older version of Android Gradle Plugin, or I was calling `assemble`, not `install`. When using AGP `3.5.0-beta04` calling `./gradlew app:installDebug` then bundletool is run and requisite split apks are automatically uploaded:

```
...
The APKs have been extracted in the directory: /var/folders/1g/mz8f0hgd0dg8ghy3pd_0llxm0000gn/T/apkSelect457573925930020942
Installing APKs 'base-xxhdpi.apk, base-master_2.apk, base-en.apk, base-x86_2.apk, my-dynamic-feature-xxhdpi.apk, my-dynamic-feature-master.apk' on 'Nexus_5X_API_25(AVD) - 7.1.1' for app:debug
01:30:05 I/SplitApkInstallerBase: Created install session 1503835220 with options -r -t -S 5653406
01:30:05 I/SplitApkInstaller: Uploading APK /var/folders/1g/mz8f0hgd0dg8ghy3pd_0llxm0000gn/T/apkSelect457573925930020942/base-xxhdpi.apk to session 1503835220
01:30:05 D/SplitApkInstaller: Executing : cmd package install-write -S 285980 1503835220 0_base-xxhdpi -
01:30:05 V/ddms: execute: running cmd package install-write -S 285980 1503835220 0_base-xxhdpi -
01:30:05 V/ddms: execute 'cmd package install-write -S 285980 1503835220 0_base-xxhdpi -' on 'emulator-5554' : EOF hit. Read: -1
01:30:05 V/ddms: execute: returning
01:30:05 D/SplitApkInstaller: Successfully uploaded base-xxhdpi.apk
01:30:05 I/SplitApkInstaller: Uploading APK /var/folders/1g/mz8f0hgd0dg8ghy3pd_0llxm0000gn/T/apkSelect457573925930020942/base-master_2.apk to session 1503835220
01:30:05 D/SplitApkInstaller: Executing : cmd package install-write -S 4887264 1503835220 1_base-master__ -
01:30:05 V/ddms: execute: running cmd package install-write -S 4887264 1503835220 1_base-master__ -
01:30:06 V/ddms: execute 'cmd package install-write -S 4887264 1503835220 1_base-master__ -' on 'emulator-5554' : EOF hit. Read: -1
01:30:06 V/ddms: execute: returning
01:30:06 D/SplitApkInstaller: Successfully uploaded base-master_2.apk
01:30:06 I/SplitApkInstaller: Uploading APK /var/folders/1g/mz8f0hgd0dg8ghy3pd_0llxm0000gn/T/apkSelect457573925930020942/base-en.apk to session 1503835220
01:30:06 D/SplitApkInstaller: Executing : cmd package install-write -S 32342 1503835220 2_base-en -
01:30:06 V/ddms: execute: running cmd package install-write -S 32342 1503835220 2_base-en -
01:30:06 V/ddms: execute 'cmd package install-write -S 32342 1503835220 2_base-en -' on 'emulator-5554' : EOF hit. Read: -1
01:30:06 V/ddms: execute: returning
01:30:06 D/SplitApkInstaller: Successfully uploaded base-en.apk
01:30:06 I/SplitApkInstaller: Uploading APK /var/folders/1g/mz8f0hgd0dg8ghy3pd_0llxm0000gn/T/apkSelect457573925930020942/base-x86_2.apk to session 1503835220
01:30:06 D/SplitApkInstaller: Executing : cmd package install-write -S 401632 1503835220 3_base-x____ -
01:30:06 V/ddms: execute: running cmd package install-write -S 401632 1503835220 3_base-x____ -
01:30:06 V/ddms: execute 'cmd package install-write -S 401632 1503835220 3_base-x____ -' on 'emulator-5554' : EOF hit. Read: -1
01:30:06 V/ddms: execute: returning
01:30:06 D/SplitApkInstaller: Successfully uploaded base-x86_2.apk
01:30:06 I/SplitApkInstaller: Uploading APK /var/folders/1g/mz8f0hgd0dg8ghy3pd_0llxm0000gn/T/apkSelect457573925930020942/my-dynamic-feature-xxhdpi.apk to session 1503835220
01:30:06 D/SplitApkInstaller: Executing : cmd package install-write -S 15362 1503835220 4_my-dynamic-feature-xxhdpi -
01:30:06 V/ddms: execute: running cmd package install-write -S 15362 1503835220 4_my-dynamic-feature-xxhdpi -
01:30:06 V/ddms: execute 'cmd package install-write -S 15362 1503835220 4_my-dynamic-feature-xxhdpi -' on 'emulator-5554' : EOF hit. Read: -1
01:30:06 V/ddms: execute: returning
01:30:06 D/SplitApkInstaller: Successfully uploaded my-dynamic-feature-xxhdpi.apk
01:30:06 I/SplitApkInstaller: Uploading APK /var/folders/1g/mz8f0hgd0dg8ghy3pd_0llxm0000gn/T/apkSelect457573925930020942/my-dynamic-feature-master.apk to session 1503835220
01:30:06 D/SplitApkInstaller: Executing : cmd package install-write -S 30826 1503835220 5_my-dynamic-feature-master -
01:30:06 V/ddms: execute: running cmd package install-write -S 30826 1503835220 5_my-dynamic-feature-master -
01:30:06 V/ddms: execute 'cmd package install-write -S 30826 1503835220 5_my-dynamic-feature-master -' on 'emulator-5554' : EOF hit. Read: -1
01:30:06 V/ddms: execute: returning
01:30:06 D/SplitApkInstaller: Successfully uploaded my-dynamic-feature-master.apk
01:30:06 V/ddms: execute: running cmd package install-commit 1503835220
01:30:14 V/ddms: execute 'cmd package install-commit 1503835220' on 'emulator-5554' : EOF hit. Read: -1
01:30:14 V/ddms: execute: returning
01:30:14 D/SplitApkInstaller: Successfully install apks: [/var/folders/1g/mz8f0hgd0dg8ghy3pd_0llxm0000gn/T/apkSelect457573925930020942/base-xxhdpi.apk, /var/folders/1g/mz8f0hgd0dg8ghy3pd_0llxm0000gn/T/apkSelect457573925930020942/base-master_2.apk, /var/folders/1g/mz8f0hgd0dg8ghy3pd_0llxm0000gn/T/apkSelect457573925930020942/base-en.apk, /var/folders/1g/mz8f0hgd0dg8ghy3pd_0llxm0000gn/T/apkSelect457573925930020942/base-x86_2.apk, /var/folders/1g/mz8f0hgd0dg8ghy3pd_0llxm0000gn/T/apkSelect457573925930020942/my-dynamic-feature-xxhdpi.apk, /var/folders/1g/mz8f0hgd0dg8ghy3pd_0llxm0000gn/T/apkSelect457573925930020942/my-dynamic-feature-master.apk]
Installed on 1 device.
```